# Is there a tool to generate customer resouce object from a Custom resource definition?

Tags: kubernetes, kubebuilder

I have a complex [kubernetes customer resource definition](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cluster-api-provider-azure/blob/main/config/crd/bases/infrastructure.cluster.x-k8s.io_azureclusteridentities.yaml). I want to generate a valid custom resource object from the definition and then replace some values with mine. This is for quick testing purposes.

Instead of creating a yaml file from scratch, I'd like to use a tool to automatically generate it. Like what kubebuilder does [when creating an API](https://book.kubebuilder.io/quick-start.html#create-an-api) (put sample objects under config/samples).

**Question**: Is there any existing tool for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, for generating custom Kubernetes objects based on template there are two solutions:

- [Kustomize](https://kustomize.io/)
- [Helm](https://helm.sh/)

Both of them have a good documentations with examples - you can find them [here](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/guides/introduction/kustomize/) for Kustomize and [here](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/quickstart/) for Helm.

For better understanding what exactly are they used for and what are differences between them I suggest reading [this](https://learnk8s.io/templating-yaml-with-code) article and [this StackOverFlow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60519939/what-is-the-difference-between-helm-and-kustomize/60897018#60897018).